# preg_replace any words in sum

Tags: php, preg-replace

Sometimes I get body to eval like this one.

```
$result = eval(45 + hjh + 78 + 89 + hello);
```

I need to replace all incalculable (like "hjh") to zero everywhere in expression to get like this one.

```
$result = eval(45 + 0 + 78 + 89 + 0);
```

Comment: You lost me at `eval`

Comment: I guess that by hjh you mean a string: "hjh" ? Am I right?

Comment: What don't like ? Do  you think I use eval to make Sum in php everytime?

Comment: Yes, I need remove any string to 0 and save expression to be to eval

Comment: eval(round(45 + 0 + 78 + 89 + 0)); and I need to save "round"

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: No)  I have to use filter function which parse the formula and remove the "incalculables"; one-line preg_replace cant to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do what you want:

```
$s = "45 + hjh + 78 + 89 + hello";
$s = preg_replace("%[^-+*/0-9 ]+%","0",$s);
$result = eval ("return $s;");
echo "R=$result\n";
```

But that detection of `incalculables` in the regular expression is likely to break in case of somewhat more *creative* input.

Answer (score 1):

Replace any character that is NOT `^` in `$allowed` with a `0`.  The delimeter used `~` cannot be in `$allowed`, so you can change it if needed:

```
$allowed = ' 0-9.*/+-';  //add everything that is allowed
$string = preg_replace("~[^$allowed]+~", '0', $string);
```

However this will change things like `1a + 1` to `10 + 1`.